# Reading text file read line by line not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know there are too many questions were asked in this topic but still I'm not able to find the reason for my failure to read a text file line by line in Python.

I'm using Python 3.4.3 and I want to read a text file line by line.

```
with open('D:\filename.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print (line)
```

I copy pasted the above lines in command prompt but nothing is printing.

I have file with Sathiya as text.

I just want to print this text in my command prompt. What I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: hi @sathiya-kumar,  you forgot the read option ---> `with open('D:\filename.txt','r') as fp:`

Comment: @AndyK `'r'` is the default. I'm guessing you are hitting enter after writing the `with` block, right?

Comment: Hi @Jim, looking at the screen capture it doesn't seem so ...

Comment: @sathiya-kumar, why don't you do the following `fp = open('D:\filename.txt')`

Comment: @Jim No I copy pasted all the three lines from notepad and pasted in command prompt and hitted enter.

Comment: @AndyK Shall i use `with open fp = open('D:\filename.txt')
 for line in fp:
  print (line)` like this?

Comment: perhaps `.....\f......` is being treated as a a special character sequence..

Comment: No error message. That `...` means that Python3 want you to continue typing a nested (indented) code or re-hit the Enter.

Comment: @Jeon Thanks! After re-hitting it worked :) Thanks alot

Comment: @Jeon Since you answered correctly i'm asking you an additional question. Why Python3 want me to re-hit or it continuing nested code in this case? By the way answer this one i will upvote your :)

Comment: It's how python shell works, you need to supply the end of the indentation.

Comment: Three choice: (1) Indent two step, and you can add code inside a for-loop. (2) Indent one step, and you can add code inside a `with` block, outside a for-loop. (3) Re-hit Enter. Tell Python that it's the end of the code. Stupid Python can't tell whether a for-loop, with block continues or not unless you explicitly tell.

Answer (score 1):

The back slash (D:**\f**ilename.txt) in the filename escapes `f` char.
That's why open could not find the file.
To handle situation you can do the followings:

You need to escape `\` char in the path:

```
with open('D:\\filename.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print (line)
```

There some other ways for example you could use forward slashes:

```
with open('D:/filename.txt') as fp:
    ...
```

Or you could use some helper methods:

```
import os

file_path = os.path.join('d:', 'filename.txt')
with open(filename) as fp:
    ...
```

You can also use raw string.

```
with open(r'D:\filename.txt') as fp:
    ...
```

Comment: Or use raw strings, which are the best way to handle both regexes and Windows paths: `r'D:\filename.txt'`

Comment: I was just adding to my answer :)

Comment: I tried all these steps and still getting nothing :(

Comment: try to use open method without `with` statement in the python shell. If it cannot find any files, code would raise `FileNotFoundError`. If it does not raise anything, test if it could read file with `read()` method: `file_to_read = open('D:/filename.txt'); print(file_to_read.read())`. If this does not print anything you need to check if your file is empty or not.

Comment: Plus 1. Thanks @scriptmonster for your help :)